# Is there any way to remember groups of startup projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Sometimes I want to start the Web API. Other times I want to start the Web API along with my Azure function project. Some times I want to start up something different.

Is there any way to remember groups of startup projects like that? Or do I have to select them manually every time?

Comment: You can create multiple solutions, each with its own startup project.

Comment: @hanspassant It takes too long to load, unfortunately.

Comment: Just don't unload it, start VS again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an extension that will let me do that:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProject